# IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 31

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, differential-equations

I am using this code to solve a nonlinear PDE. Since I am using an implicit (backwards-difference) method I am required to solve a set of nonlinear algebraic equations. In my attempt to do this, I get the error:

```
    f[1:M, q] = U[1:M, q+1] - r * (U[2: M+1, q+1] + U[0:M-1, q+1]) + 2 * r * U[1:M, q+1] \
IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 31
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import math
from scipy.sparse import spdiags
from numpy.linalg import inv

M = 30
dx = 1 / M
r = 0.25

tmax = 0.2
dt = r * dx**2
N = math.floor(tmax / dt)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, M + 1)
t = np.linspace(0, tmax, N + 1)


U = np.zeros((M + 1, N + 1))                           # Initial array for solution u(x, t)

U[:, 0] = 40 * x**2 * (1 - x) / 3                      # Initial condition 
U[0, :] = 0                                            # Boundary condition at x = 0
U[-1, :] = 0                                           # Boundary condition at x = 1 


for q in range(1, N):
    U[:, q+1] = U[:, q]
    for p in range(1, 10):
        f = np.zeros((M + 1, M + 1))
        #f[0, q] = 0
        #f[M, q] = 0
        f[1:M, q] = U[1:M, q+1] - r * (U[2: M+1, q+1] + U[0:M-1, q+1]) + 2 * r * U[1:M, q+1] \
                    - r * U[1:M, q+1] * U[2:M+1, q+1]**2 + r * U[1:M, q+1]**2 * U[2:M+1, q+1] - r * U[1:M, q+1]**3
        updiag = -r - 2 * r * U[p, q + 1] * U[p + 1, q + 1] + 2 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2
        diag = 1 + 2 * r + 3 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2 - 4 * r * U[p, q + 1] * U[p+1, q+1] - 2 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2
        lowdiag = r
        Jdata = np.array([31 * [diag], 31 * [lowdiag], 31 * [updiag]])
        Diags = [0, -1, 1]
        J = spdiags(Jdata, Diags, 31, 31).toarray()
        d = inv(J) * f
        u = U[:, q+1]
        u = u + d
        U[1, q + 1] = 0
        U[M, q + 1] = 0


T, X = np.meshgrid(t, x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(T, X, U, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')
ax.set_zlabel('u(x, t)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('BDImplSol.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The solution should look like this (which I produced from an explicit method)

[image]

Update:

Ok so I adjusted my code accordingly

```
for q in range(1, N):
    U[:, q+1] = U[:, q]
    for p in range(1, 10):
        f = np.zeros((M+1, M+1))
        for k in range(2, M):
            f = U[k, q+1] - r * (U[k+1, q+1] + U[k-1, q+1]) + 2 * r * U[k, q+1] \
              - r * U[k, q+1] * U[k+1, q+1]**2 + r * U[k+1, q+1]**2 * U[k, q+1] - r * U[k, q+1]**3


        updiag = -r - 2 * r * U[p, q + 1] * U[p+1, q + 1] + 2 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2
        diag = 1 + 2 * r + 3 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2 - 4 * r * U[p+1, q + 1] * U[p+1, q+1] - 2 * r * U[p, q + 1]**2
        lowdiag = r
        Jdata = np.array([31 * [diag], 31 * [lowdiag], 31 * [updiag]])
        Diags = [0, -1, 1]
        J = spdiags(Jdata, Diags, 31, 31).toarray()
        d = inv(J) * f
        u = U[:, q+1]
        u = u + d
        U[1, q + 1] = 0
        U[M, q + 1] = 0
```

which produces

[image]

I'm pretty sure the issue is with f. I don't think I have expressed the fact that I want:

```
f[0, q]  = 0
f[1:M-1, q] = 0
f[-1, q] = 0
```

correctly.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: since the array is of size 31, and Python is zero-indexed, the indices of that array goes from 0 to 30 inclusively.

Comment: Right but I'm not entirely sure how to get around that,. I need to define the (M+1)th space-point for the discretisation formula.

Comment: So are you trying to add a new value to the array? I don't think you can add it on the fly; instead, create a new array of size 32, copy the first 31 values in, then assign the index-31 value in the newly created slot.

Comment: That's not how I interpreted what I am trying to do, but I'll try it

Comment: I didn't entirely understand what you meant but I've made some progress

Comment: Instead of         `J = spdiags(Jdata, Diags, 31, 31).toarray();  d = inv(J) * f` you should better use `J = spdiags(Jdata, Diags, 31, 31); d = spsolve(J,f)`

Comment: In your first version, define `f` just as vector, not as matrix. What is the meaning of the magic number 10? Why is `p` used as space index?

Comment: Was it required of you to approximate the first derivative with a one-sided difference quotient or could you switch to the central one? You missed a factor 2 in the binomial formula for the square of the difference quotient. However, discussion on the correct design of the discretized system should happen at scicomp.SE or math.SE with mathjax formula support.

Comment: Sorry just seen this. The first derivative is approximated using a backwards difference. Edit: I find i and j get mixed up easily and N has already been used to I've used p and q for space and time indexes respectively. The Matlab code this is inspired by uses 10, I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Your construction of `J` is wrong, the (sub-)diagonal entries should not be equal. Is that intended to be a Newton solver or just some ad-hoc fixed-point solver?

Comment: Yeah I'm using a Newton solver for the nonlinear system. ```spsolve``` is for linear systems. I thought that by the ```Diags``` line I have set up the first subdiagonal to be non-zero but the rest are zero as the matrix is sparse right?

Comment: Context PDE: u_t = u_xx + u(u_x)^2

Comment: The environment here is not very friendly to formulas, as SO is more concerned with coding problems. For algorithm design, what your discretization and implicit solver is, you should move the discussion to scicomp.SE. If you go there, also add some steps of the formal derivation of the implicit system.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help

Comment: Answer now there in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36666/backwards-difference-implicit-method-for-nonlinear-parabolic-pde, it was indeed much easier to write down the partial derivatives that make up `J` there.